# RabbitMQ cannot establish TCP connection to any configured hosts

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, eventmachine

I am trying to run AMQP with bunny and event machine. Whenever I try to use a worker, bunny complains about the following: **Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts**

I don't see port 5672 anywhere when I run netstat. Further, the output of nmap -p 5672 0.0.0.0 gives the following:

```
Nmap scan report for 0.0.0.0
Host is up (0.000092s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5672/tcp closed amqp
```

My configuration file ($HOME/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config is as follows:

```
[{mnesia, [{dump_log_write_threshold, 1000}]},
    {rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [5672]},
    {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@jordan-dev'], disc}}
]}].
```

Could anybody explain to me why rabbitmq can not connect to the tcp port specified in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Is your firewall configured properly?

Try `telnet ip port` from some machine is see if it's reachable. If it's not reachable then add the firewall rule.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
```